# PYPI - 403 Invalid or non-existent authentication information

Tags: pypi

I will pay US$100 in BTC or via PayPal to whoever helps to solve this for me.
Happy to have a call - my email is shasa.foster.frm@gmail.com

I am try to publish a package to PYPI (with the token name and token value as this is required by PyPI as at October 2023) but I keep getting the 403 Invalid or non-existent authentication information error.

[image]

I have followed the [instructions](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi) meticulously, and have tried on a Linux PC (Ubuntu), Windows PC (via command line) and also via Github actions (Ubuntu).

If I try to publish with my PyPI account username and password it tells me I must use the  token name and token value.

[image]

[image]

[image]